# Django and mysql fetching yesterday's login count

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using Django and rest-auth. I already have a working code to fetch today's and yesterday's login counts in my Django application as follows:

```
def get_analytics(request):

    total_users = User.objects.all().count()
    total_users_games = User.objects.filter(username__startswith='yg_').count()
    # Number of users who dogged in once to our system today
    today_login_count= User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now().date()).count()
    today_login_count_memoryGames= User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now().date(), username__startswith='yg_').count()
    yesterday_login_count = User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now().date() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)).count()
    yesterday_login_count_memoryGames = User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now().date() - timezone.timedelta(days=1), username__startswith='yg_').count()
```

There are usernames starting with 'yg' and few starting with 'yg_' responsible for two different frontends.

Today's login count is correct, I crosschecked from database. However I am not sure about yesterday's login count, it looks like the number which I get is not correct (i.e. today's login count will be tomorrow: yesterday's login count, so these numbers should be same). I suspect the code for yesterday's login count gives me those users who did login yesterday and not today, where as what I want is all the users who logged in yesterday. I ran following query with yesterday's date and got 4 results and that's actually what

```
yesterday_login_count_memoryGames = User.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now().date() - timezone.timedelta(days=1), username__startswith='yg_').count()
```

gives me.

```
select username, last_login from auth_user where username like '%yg\_%' and last_login like '%2016-09-06%';
```

I am cross checking in my database with following sql query:

```
select username, last_login from auth_user where username like '%yg\_%' and last_login like '%2016-09-07%';
```

How can I write a query to fetch yesterdays's login count like this?

Also, in this line `username__startswith='yg_'` do I need escape character? like username__startswith='yg_'? to get the count of logins with usernames starting with yg_?

Answer (score 2):

Relying on `last_login` isn't going to cut it and will give unreliable data. You will need to store each successful login event in another table foreign keyed to the user along with the login time.

```
class LoginEvent(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  login_date = models.DateField()
```

Note that you wont need to store more than one login in a day. When a user logs in, check if an entry with todays date exists or not. If it exists, then do need not do anything. If it doesn't exist, you will need to insert a new row with todays date. You could even set up a `unique_together` constraint for `('user', 'login_data')` to enforce this.

After this, the following query will be able to give you the login count data you need.

```
yesterday = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=1)
LoginEvent.objects.filter(login_date=yesterday, user__username__startswith='yg_').count()
```

This will create the necessary inner join and give you the counts.

Comment: Oh! this was totally unexpected, thanks for a quick reply! I have one question though: how would I insert a row in this table when someone logs in? Right now, I do not have any custom user model, I am using travix rest-auth to authenticate. Can you perhaps give me more code for this LoginEvent class with this insertion etc?

Comment: @Nitish I'm not familiar with travix-rest-auth. I'd suggest posting a new question along the lines of "How to add manual post user creation logic  with travix-rest-auth"